# What's the difference between GLSurfaceView and Sceneform?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

Maybe this is a strange question, but what's the difference between `GLSurfaceView` and `Sceneform`, and which is better for Android ARCore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## About `Sceneform`

**`Sceneform` is a high-level 3D framework** and satellite of ARCore. Sceneform makes it straight-forward to realistically render 3D scenes for AR and VR android apps using real-time physically based [Filament](https://google.github.io/filament/) renderer. You don't even have to learn OpenGL discipline. A Sceneform's scene graph API allows you import, view and build 3D assets in `.fbx`, `.glTF` and `.obj` file formats.

## About `GLSurfaceView`

**`GLSurfaceView` class extends a `SurfaceView` parent class and is used for 2D drawing and displaying OpenGL rendering**. You can use this view in ARCore app as a custom view for 2D OpenGL rendering.

```
open class GLSurfaceView : SurfaceView, SurfaceHolder.Callback2
```

Here's GLSurfaceView's hierarchical place:

```
kotlin.Any
    ↳ android.view.View
        ↳ android.view.SurfaceView
            ↳ android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
```

Comment: Can I use scenform with latest arcore sdk?

Comment: Yes, you can. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62453399/google-sceneform-is-it-deprecated-any-replacement/62694454#62694454

Comment: But Sceneform is deprecated.

Comment: You can still use versions 1.16 and 1.17. Sceneform is not unsupported, however. It's no longer actively maintaining...

Comment: ok, can you tell me why google is not maintaining sceneform? Because I am struggling with latest OpenGL demo from many days. But no luck. Not every person has that much knowledge of OpenGL lol.

Comment: No one knows why Google does what it does)) Seemingly it prepares a release of new rendering technology...

Comment: Can you suggest me Where 3d face mask design available for arcore. Or tutorial for making that exactly.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen any robust Face Tracking tutorials for ARCore.