# Google Sceneform – Is it deprecated? Any replacement?

Tags: android, arcore, virtual-reality, sceneform

I use in my ARCore project Sceneform. It seems that this project is now mentioned as [Archived](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk) by Google. More info we can find [here](https://developers.google.com/sceneform/develop) or on this [page](https://developers.google.com/sceneform).

I don't understand if Google really abandoned this SDK, or if it is - or will be - directly integrated in ARCore SDK?

Thanks for any information concerning the future of this SDK and a potential replacements.

Comment: It does seem odd that Google hasn't stated something official on this. I wonder if they are going to recommend using Filament : https://github.com/google/filament directly.

Comment: Similar question on reddit, with a comment by @romain-guy (a member of Android dev team): https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/glduwe/is_sceneform_dead/

Comment: @elprl Filament is great but it's not an equivalent technology to Sceneform. Not even apples to oranges, they are absolutely on a different level. I like the Sceneform goodies layering on top of ARCore like ArFragment, TransformableNode, PinchGestures, ShapeFactroy and so on...

Comment: So nobody knows why they discontinued it?

Answer (score 45):

#### Edited 2022:

**Sceneform maintained and successor:**

- Sceneform - Java Continuation : [SceneView/sceneform-android](https://github.com/SceneView/sceneform-android)
- SceneView - Kotlin Successor : [SceneView/sceneview-android](https://github.com/SceneView/sceneview-android)

**Differences with Google Sceneform (1.15.0, 1.16.0, 1.17.0 and 1.17.1)**

- No plugin needed: Use **gltf and glb 3D models** files directly from assets, res/raw, local file or http/https url **instead of sfa, sfb, fbx, obj,...**
- Latest versions of [ARCore SDK](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk) and [Google Filament](https://github.com/google/filament)
- Latest gradle dependencies including AndroidX, LifecycleScope/Coroutines (**SceneView only**),...
- Available as `mavenCentral()` dependency
- **Augmented Images** supported
- **Augmented Faces** supported
- `glb` or `gltf` for 3D models (**animations supported**)
- `hdr` or `ktx` for Environement (IndirectLight + Skybox)
- 3D only usage supported and single dependency without ARCore (**SceneView only**)
- **VideoNode** for MediaPlayer (mp4, avi,...) Video 3D Node
- Horizontal/Vertical Plane Placement
- **Depth** occlusion and placement (**SceneView only**)
- **InstantPlacement** (**SceneView only**)
- **HdrLightEstimation** with adjustements between more Spectacular or Realistic
- Simple **Model Viewer** for basic usage, with only ArSceneView parameters
- Less OpenGL knowlege needed

Comment: It does seem to be really well maintained as of March 2021 ..  :O

Comment: That's great work, Thomas Gorisse!

Comment: Thank you for you efforts,, My I know why did you switch to Kotlin?

Answer (score 24):

***Updated***: September 05, 2023.

### About Sceneform replacement on Google IO '21

Let's listen to what ***Fred Sauer*** (Developer Advocate at Google on the ARCore team) told us about replacements of Sceneform. Here's a [link to video](https://io.google/2021/session/decb4846-3dca-42ac-8e68-2a41efa51887/?lng=en) called AMA : ARCore (time 06:25).

---

### Sceneform fork (Unofficial Sceneform 1.21)

This is the [continuation](https://github.com/SceneView/sceneform-android) of the archived Sceneform.

---

### About last official versions

There are three official versions to choose from:

- Sceneform 1.17.1
- Sceneform 1.16
- Sceneform 1.15

Several months ago Google [recommended](https://developers.google.com/sceneform/develop/build-scene) not to use the latest version `Sceneform 1.17` due to Maven artifacts (now it might work normally but it's still a question). `Sceneform 1.16` isn't available via Android Studio plugins' menu because, as you said, its status is `Archived` (I should say `Abandoned`). Release `1.16` supports `glTF`/`glTB` formats, instead of `SFA` and `SFB` assets. And `Sceneform 1.16` went open-source. Hence you can download it from GitHub. The only thing I don't understand why Google released `Sceneform 1.17` if `Sceneform 1.16` was archived?!

So there are two 100%-working versions at the moment – `Sceneform 1.16` and `Sceneform 1.15`.

---

### Sceneform 1.16 installation

- For downloading `Sceneform 1.16` for `ARCore Android` use [this link](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/releases/tag/v1.16.0) on GitHub.
- Use these thorough [instructions](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk) to include and build the `Sceneform 1.16` SDK with your app.

---

### Google discontinued Sceneform

Google didn't prepare a release of a new official 3D rendering engine (even using Filament as a base). **Original ARCore team** fell apart, that's why new ARCore features are implemented so slow.

Comment: The ARCore SDK for Unity is deprecated, and no longer supported in Unity 2020 and later. This SDK should only be used by developers working on existing projects which are unable to migrate to Unity's AR Foundation.

Comment: Thanks @Softlion, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: So the "solution" is to migrate to AR Foundation, which is a 1800$/y/seat product.

Comment: Link to google I/O video no longer working.

Comment: Hi @stackunderflows, I've replaced the link.

Comment: With sceneform 1.15 there are a lot of examples that helps the developer more,  so that it is hard to switch to 1.16, I have build solar system example  and it is working perfectly, but the bad thing is that the sceneform plugin is deprecated,  maybe the good idea is to combine what we have right now to develop new solutions https://developers.google.com/sceneform/develop/samples  https://github.com/SceneView/sceneform-android

Answer (score 7):

It's a sad story, I like Sceneform and for me it will not be easy to simple replace it. Because of that I forked it and updated the lib to androidx and filament 1.7. https://github.com/RGregat/sceneform-android-sdk. What is not working is the new Depth API introduced in ARCore 1.18. I'm not sure how difficult it is to implement it into Sceneform, because it depends on the Fragment Shader.

Comment: It looks like your fork is also archived. Is there any fork in active development?

Comment: The readme is misleading. Sorry for that. You can use this fork, but an active development might be difficult. For example the new Depth API requires access to the Fragment Shader, That is something you don't have really with Sceneform. Maybe with Filament, because we have in theory access to it, but I'm not sure.