# Rendering the object in ARCore environment without the help of Sceneform

Tags: android-studio, opengl-es, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

We can easily render object in ARCore with the help of Sceneform with just few lines of code. But I have to do it without Sceneform.

Does anyone know how to do it?

The challenges are making the object renderable, placing anchors and anchor nodes in the AR scene. I guess there is some method in OpenGL to do this but I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 1):

`Sceneform` is not only an ARCore's companion, it's also its rendering engine that helps us read in a scene geometry and calculate light physics for all PBR shaders.

If you wanna implement another rendering engine, make sure it's able to load all polygonal models into AR scene with readable shaders and textures. It's not easy to implement a rendering engine from scratch. ARCore doesn't render any geometry. ARCore's purpose is to track a surrounding environment, implement `Environmental Understanding` principles, estimate a level of light in real-world room and then put there stable anchors for models.

However [Sceneform is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62453399/google-sceneform-is-it-deprecated-any-replacement).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Actually i am working on an already built AR App and when i tried to include Arfragment in the app,it crashes(due to crashing i needed some other method for rendering as i asked in the question).Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Hi @TusharKumarRai, Publish it as another question, please.

Comment: Yeah i asked. Here is the link of the question -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62592904/how-to-render-objects-in-just-a-line-ar-app

Comment: sceneform is deprecated.