# How to render objects in Just A Line AR App?

Tags: android-studio, opengl-es, augmented-reality, arcore, android-augmented-reality

**I have to render objects over lines drawn in Just a Line AR App**.But when i am trying to include arfragment, "**app is not able to find a place to draw line**".Also when i am trying to include view renderable class for showing 2d texts into 3d scene,i am getting this error:

```
"No implementation found for long com.google.android.filament.Stream.CreateBuilder()".
```

Any idea on how to resolve this issue?