# What is Google Sceneform SDK exactly?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I am new to AR development. I started with some tutorials like [this](https://medium.com/@harivigneshjayapalan/arcore-cupcakes-5-augmented-faces-api-2ca78681228e#:%7E:text=on%20ARCore%20fundamentals.-,Augmented%20Faces%20API,like%20Facebook%20and%20SnapChat%20filters.) and found them using [Sceneform](https://developers.google.com/sceneform/develop), but not explaining what Sceneform is and why is it used.

Searching over the internet isn't giving me clear answers.

I am confused as to how is `Sceneform` related to `ARCore` or how it is different from ARCore.

Isn't ARCore enough without Sceneform?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sceneform SDK allows you import and view 3D models (in such formats as `.obj`, `.fbx` or `.glTF`) and then render realistic 3D scenes for ARCore apps or VR apps, without having to learn OpenGL. Sceneform includes a high-level Scene Graph API, a Physically Based Renderer (PBR) provided by [Filament](https://github.com/google/filament) and Android Studio plugin for building 3D assets. ARCore is not able to import and render 3D models. ARCore is made for tracking and scene understanding stages.

*In AR app development industry, Sceneform is ARCore's general companion*.

However, Sceneform SDK has been archived and no longer maintained by Google. There's no any replacement for Sceneform except pure Filament renderer. Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62453399/google-sceneform-is-it-deprecated-any-replacement/62694454#62694454) if you need more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Am I correct in thinking that Unity 3D doesn't require Sceneform because it can import and render 3D scenes itself?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. You can read about it using a link (more detail).

Comment: There's a sentence: "However, if you are building a new project, consider using the Unity ARCore SDK for Android. It uses Unity to render objects in 3d space and provides an easier way to create an ARCore app".

Comment: There's a maintained version of Sceneform https://github.com/SceneView/sceneform-android