# Can we use SceneForm/SceneKit without ARCORE/ARKit for 3d model rendering

Tags: tensorflow, scenekit, arkit, arcore, sceneform

Thank you for taking time to read this question.
We are developing a ML Object Detection mobile app and we are planning to place object within the Bounding box when the object is detected.
Currently we are searching for solutions which will help us place a 3d model within the bounding box. We want the 3d model to be placed on the bounding box with a transparent background to make it look 'AR'. We don't want to move to ARCore because we want to stick to our ML solution.

Can you please let me know if we use SceneForm without ARCORE for 3d model rendering.

PS : Right now we have used flutter for cross platform development. But we are looking to move to native development because we are not able to find any flutter widgets/libraries to render other 3d models on a transparent background

Answer (score 2):

SceneKit is a 3D framework and rendering engine that you can use with ARKit or without it. It's not ARKit's satellite, it's rather a standalone SDK that reads in 3D geometry, plays animation and dynamics and renders shaders and shadows. In other words SceneKit was made for VR development. Second VR/AR Apple's framework is RealityKit. You can read about these SDKs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60505755/high-quality-rendering-realitykit-vs-scenekit-vs-metal/60513052#60513052).

You can also use Sceneform SDK without ARCore. Pity but at the moment Sceneform repository has been archived and it no longer actively maintaining by Google (use Filament instead). You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62453399/google-sceneform-is-it-deprecated-any-replacement/63653616#63653616).

Both, SceneKit and Sceneform, can render 3D models on a transparent background but this feature doesn't exist in these SDKs out-of-the-box. You need to apply corresponding advanced methodology to get a desirable results.