# Augmented image anchor position changed frequently

Tags: arcore, sceneform, android-augmented-reality, augmentedimage

ArCore Augmented image anchor created from image center pose changed after some time and it leads to look like the object not stable and it is drifting.Hoe to avoid anchor position change.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the tracking really imporoved when migrating from AR Core version 1.17 to 1.20, but then they really changed the codebase a lot so now it uses a whole separate texture for keeping depth info. Otherwise, you just have to pick really good surfaces to anchor on. I used to carry around a placemat or facecloth with a good design to do demos...

Comment: For surface detection it is good to use some floor with features. But for Augmented image I have used an image with image score of 90 but still the anchor is not stable. I have crated a global anchor as soon as get FULL_TRACKING and added 3d objects.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have more than one anchor in the mix? Once you've captured your one anchor make sure to toggle off any code that's dealing with subsequent anchors. Also what device are you testing with?

Comment: Yes as soon as I created an anchor make a flag as true and add 3d objects and next time it will not execute code to create anchor and add 3d objects. And tested in Pixels 4 XL and Samsung tab s6.

Comment: I would think the Pixel 4 XL would be well calibrated. I know my new Pixel 4a is much better than the original Pixel One (where the anchor would drift, particularly in some types of lighting). But then, I was forced to upgrade AR Core and Android 11 to compile for the new device, so that could have something to do with it. If you post a video to YouTube or Drive, someone may recognize what's going on from the way the grid drifts around...

Comment: Perhaps then you toggled off too much code after you captured your anchor, and some of their code needs to keep running to stablize the tracking...

Comment: Instead of using AnchorNode directly I have created a intermediate node and set anchornode pose to the intermediate node for each frame. It looks better than before and objects stay in same place but looks like shaking of objects.I have created anchor on arsceneview session with first detected image pose and move camera parallel to us to see the animation,here tracking goes to last known pose. So is it tacking good only in fulltracking and not stable in last known pose?

Comment: Uh, what version of AR Core are you basing this on? They have been changing things around a lot the last few months, so I only change things as little as possible with their base-code before piling mine ontop of it.  Also, I heard somewhere on StackOverFlow that support for sceneview was discontinued. Do you have the exact same problem before you add that to the mix?

Comment: I am using ARCore 1.21.0 and sceneform 1.15.0

Comment: I am still on 1.20 so I can't help you there, but perhaps you should research whatever going on, or not going on, with sceneform like they say here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62453399/google-sceneform-is-it-deprecated-any-replacement

Comment: Is it means shall I need to move to filament  or native openGL code insteadof sceneform  ? I am not sure it is possible because this project already completed with sceneform. But sceneform api shows some depth api.

Comment: I don't know what it means, but I've learned over the decades that the more intermediary code you depend on, the more you're going to be abandoned, even if its open source. I have no doubt many of the people using Unity are going to be in trouble when some big company takes it over and they faze-out their enemies platforms...